# protobuf service can not found in the output file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I define a rpc service in a proto file, but I can not found any interface or method in the output java file.

```
$ protoc -v 
libprotoc 2.5.0
```

proto file:

```
service EchoService {
    rpc Echo (Person) returns (Person);
}
```

compile script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find src/main/proto -name "*.proto"`; do
    protoc --proto_path=src/main/proto --java_out=src/main/java/ $file
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [`java_generic_services` option](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options).  You need to add this to your `.proto` file:

```
option java_generic_services = true;
```

However, this is only useful if you have some RPC implementation to use with it (or want to write your own).  The option defaults to false because it is expected that most RPC implementations will want to write a custom code generator rather than use the "generic" generated services.